# How to download lots of pictures sent via Google Drive in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-drive, images

I got sent a few hundred pictures from Gmail to Gmail, but on their end they were sent using Google Drive, so they are just links, and there's not a “download all” link. And I can't access the parent folder to get to them all that way either.

What can I do?

How can I download all pictures at once?

Comment: The image isn't avaliable, can you repost?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Gmail, use Google Drive.

1. Go to https://drive.google.com
2. Check the box next to each item you want to download
3. Click "More" above the list
4. Click "Download"

The links you are seeing in Gmail are links to items you have in your Google Drive. Using the full Google Drive interface will give you more options on how to interact with the items.